# How can I search a directory of files using static methods and return an object?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to learn how to write utility classes and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is a good candidate for a utility class.  I'm still very new to java and trying to understand how and when to do certain things conceptually.

I have a class that has only static methods.  And I think whenever my `search()` method is recursively called, the data that it originally had is being lost.  My class is setup like this:

```
public class MyClassUtil {

    public static List<MyObjectData> findStuff(File path, List<String> listOfMyStuff) {
        String listAsString = convertListToString(listOfMyStuff);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(listAsString);

        List<MyObjectData> myObjectData = search(path, pattern);

        return myObjectData;
    }

    private static final String convertListToString(List<String> list) {

        // This method converts a given list to a string.  It works fine!
    }

    private static final List<MyObjectData> search(File directory, Pattern p) {

        List<MyObjectData> dataInFile = new ArrayList<MyStringData>();

        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        try {
                            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                            boolean found = m.find();

                            if (found) {
                                dataInFile.add(new MyObjectData(m.group(2), true));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception E) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                search(file, p);
            }
            return dataInFile;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting anything back (although I know something should be returned).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @PhilippSander I'm not getting anything back because of the recursive calls to the search method (I think).  Does my use of a utility class in this situation make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't add the result from the recursive call.

Change:

```
     if(file.isDirectory()) { search(file, p); }
```

to

```
     if(file.isDirectory()) { dataInFile.addAll(search(file, p)); }
```

Comment: Wow, I was stuck on this for over a day and I was afraid to ask the question here.  Thank you so much, this was my problem.

Comment: Sure, why not. I would probably divide it into specialized utility classes, like `MyFileUtil` for file operations and `MyStringUtil` for string operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the recursive code add files to a list that you pass in. Example just lists every file

```
private static void recursiveFill(List<File> files, File path) {
    if (path.isFile()) {
        files.add(path);
        return;
    }
    if (path.isDirectory()) {
        File[] innerFiles = path.listFiles();
        for (File file : innerFiles) {
            recursiveFill(files, file);
        }
    }
}

public static List<File> listFileIn(File path) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    recursiveFill(result, path);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> files = listFileIn(new File("."));
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

You can do it like you did but you will have to use the return value in

```
if(file.isDirectory()) { search(file, p); }
```

and merge those results into the list you return.